# Multiple flexsliders on same page, want all with same properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here, thought this was fairly straight forward.  I want my top slider to not start automatically (which I have working correctly).  I want the second slider to do the same.  Any time I add any change to the #secondary-slider, they both quit working.

```
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="Images/Web/M2M/1.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><img src="Images/Web/M2M/2.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><img src="Images/Web/M2M/3.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><img src="Images/Web/M2M/4.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="secondary-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="Images/Web/SRY/1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Images/Web/SRY/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Images/Web/SRY/3.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#main-slider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        slideshow: false,
    });

    $('#secondary-slider').flexslider()
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.  They both display perfectly correct, but the second slider needs to carryover the `slidershow: false` and `animation: fade`.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm confused. You want both sliders to work the same, But you only send the options object to the first one? Should you send it to the second one too?

Comment: Well thats what I thought, but when I add animation and slideshow options to secondary-slider, both stop working.

Comment: Here is a version running 2 flexsliders on the one page http://jsfiddle.net/BSwJn/159/

Comment: I also just noticed that your html has closing anchor tags without opening anchor tags in the first slider